# Como eu faço para encontrar o caracter '[' em uma string com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho a *string* `"Package sem arquivo [ 11/7/2017 10:16:32 AM ]"` e queria encontrar o caractere `[` e saber sua posição.

```
var indRem = pkgName.search('/[/');
```

Tentei desta forma e não rolou, podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o `indexOf` que ele retornará a posição:

```
var text = "teste [ teste";
console.log(text.indexOf("["));
```

Mas caso queira pegar a data e hora que está dentro de `"[]"` (que eu suponho que seja isso que queira fazer) pode fazer o seguinte (gambiarra):

```
var text = "Package sem arquivo [ 11/7/2017 10:16:32 AM ]";
var text2 = text.split("[");
var text3 = text2[1].split(" ");
console.log(text3[1] + " - " + text3[2]);
```

Modo mais correto, mas um pouco avançado:

```
var text = "Package sem arquivo [ 11/7/2017 10:16:32 AM ]";
var datahora = text.match(/\[ (.*) \]/).split(" ");

console.log(datahora[0] + " - " + datahora[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `indexOf` que irá retornar a posição da *primeira* ocorrência:

```
"Package sem arquivo [ 11/7/2017 10:16:32 AM ]".indexOf("["); // 20
```

Para saber de todas as ocorrências:

```js
let str = "Package sem arquivo [[ 11/7/2017 10:16:32 AM []";

function indexes(expressao, texto) {
  return texto.split('').reduce((a, b, c) => b === expressao ? a.concat(c) : a, [])
}

console.log(indexes("[", str));
```